# jLinq with dynamic select

Tags: jquery, linq, select

I am using [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq/demo) to query my `Array` of `Objects`
But I want to query dynamically getting the values of my `Selects`

this is my exemple:

```
<select id="firt"><option>Select 1</option></select>
<select id="last"><option>Select 2</option></select>
<select id="phone"><option>Select 3</option></select>

myNewArray = jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )
             .equals( "first", $( "#first" ).find( "option:selected" )  
             .equals( "last",  $( "#last" ).find( "option:selected" )
             .equals( "phone", $( "#phone" ).find( "option:selected" )
             .group( "state" );
```

but I want something like this:

```
myNewArray = jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )
             //for each selected option
             .group( "state" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function makeQuery() {
  var query = 'jlinq.from( array ).sort( "date" )';

  $('select').each(function(index) {
    query += '.equals( "' + this.id + '", "' + this.value + '")';
  });

  query += '.group( "state" );'

  $('#query').html(query);

  //myNewArray = eval(query);
}
```